# Unanswered Questions > my tags should filter out questions that you have answered

Tags: feature-request, tags, unanswered-questions, tag-watching

The purpose of this page is to show a user every question that is tagged with one or more favorite tags that does not have an accepted or up voted answer. However, if the user answers a question, that question still remains. That doesn't serve much of a purpose, since it doesn't help me find questions that could still benefit from me answering them.

---

It's now 2019 and this doesn't appear to have been reviewed. This continues to be an issue. Perhaps it's overcome by the new navigation tools, but those haven't rolled out across the network yet and I'm primarily looking at sites other than Stack Overflow.

I need to spend a little bit of time looking at the new navigation tools, but I'm hoping that either there is a reasonable timeline to roll them out across the network or things can be done to improve the ability to find questions to answer until they are rolled out.

Comment: Not sure it's a good idea. Maybe you learned new things since you answered? Maybe after taking a second look, you can improve your answer? (having score of 0 or less means there's probably something to improve). What I would totally support is adding an option to search in the Unanswered Questions page, with all the search options

Comment: @ShadowWizard Perhaps, but you can find your answers easily, including your low voted answers. But let's look at my usage - I have 38 favorite tags on Programmers and 30 on PM. Some are low-participation tags. They aren't 0, but they tend to not get a lot of attention or visibility. If I'm answering an older question where the asker isn't an active participant and I do this a lot, the list of unanswered questions become too hard to use for what I image is its intended use - a list of questions that I may be able to answer based on my interests that don't have a good answer yet.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Adding filters to the Unanswered questions is totally a valid solution to this feature-request. Ultimately, I just want to be able to use Unanswered Questions > my tags as a queue of sorts to manage questions in areas that I'm most knowledgeable about.